# Scrape data from multiple pages of a website using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, data-collection

I want to crawl around 500 articles from the site [AlJazeera Website](https://www.aljazeera.com) and want to collect 4 tags i.e

- URL
- Title
- Tags
- Author

I have written the script that collects data from home page, but it only collects couple of articles. Other articles are in different categories. How can I iterate through 500 articles. Is there an efficient way to do it.

```
import bs4
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from collections import Counter
page = requests.get('https://www.aljazeera.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
article = soup.find(id='more-top-stories')
inside_articles= article.find_all(class_='mts-article mts-default-article')
article_title = [inside_articles.find(class_='mts-article-title').get_text() for inside_articles in inside_articles]
article_dec = [inside_articles.find(class_='mts-article-p').get_text() for inside_articles in inside_articles]
tag = [inside_articles.find(class_='mts-category').get_text() for inside_articles in inside_articles]
link = [inside_articles.find(class_='mts-article-title').find('a') for inside_articles in inside_articles]
```

Comment: in websites only 6 articles under more top stories. there are no 500 articles and beautifulsoup only extract data from Html parser

Comment: classes are different for different sections in the website. What is the better way to approach this problem.

Comment: yes, you can get articles from different categories still there is no 500 articles.

Comment: is beautifulsoup is a better way ? or should I explore other libraries as well. Can u suggest any

Comment: if you want to scrape data from the static websites or low-level complex site then you should use beautifulsoup.When you want to deal with Core Javascript-based web Applications then Selenium would be a great choice. 
 if you are dealing with complex Scraping operation that requires huge speed and with low power consumption then Scrapy would be a great choice.

Comment: one more thing, if you print link variable, it's output is something like <a href="/news/2020/01/rescue-ship-captain-conviction-overturned-malta-court-200107104527407.html" onclick="sendGAEvent('Home - More Top News', 'click' ,'/news/2020/01/rescue-ship-captain-conviction-overturned-malta-court-200107104527407.html');">

Comment: I only want the url, but I could not work it out.

Comment: use get_text() method for extract data from element.

Comment: get_text() and text() method extracts the text or title in this case. I want to just extract the href tag out of it

Comment: `link = [inside_articles.find(class_='mts-article-title').find('a')['href'] for inside_articles in inside_articles]` try this

Comment: it's my pleasure, you can upvote the comment if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scrapy for this purpose.

```
import scrapy
import json
class BlogsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogs'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/05/fbi-texas-naval-base-shooting-terrorism-related-200521211619145.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.css('body'):
            current_script = data.xpath("//script[contains(., 'mainEntityOfPage')]/text()").extract_first()
            json_data = json.loads(current_script)
            yield {
                'name': json_data['headline'],
                'author': json_data['author']['name'],
                'url': json_data['mainEntityOfPage'],
                'tags': data.css('div.article-body-tags ul li a::text').getall(),
            }
```

Save this file to file.py and run it by

```
$scrapy crawl blogs -o output.json
```

But configure scrapy structure first.